# Increase the effect of Ambient Occlusion with Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I use cycles render to bake Ambient Occlusion map. However, the shadow on the object is too light. I want to increase and make it darker. I have been trying to adjust ColorRamp and it didn't change anything. I might have done something wrong.

**Q:** How to increase the effect?

So, I created a new cube and did what you suggested, but there's nothing change. The shadow didn't get darker like yours. That's exactly what I've been trying to figure out. It must be nice if someone can show me a tutorial! I'm kind a beginner! :D

To make my question more clear, these images below might give some clues. I really don't know how to fix this!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using fairly light colors in the ramp. I suggest to start with a simple B/W ramp to change the contrast on the AO node. Once you get the desired intensity, then only start changing the color ramp.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to do. But I still cannot figure out why my cube and plane dis not turn out like yours, or maybe I need the "Viewer" tab?

Comment: The viewer is just an emission node but using the Node Wrangler addons which names it "viewer" (I highly recommend this addon). However you can also drive  the color input of a Principled BSDF node with this ramp.

Comment: Bruno- It's not working the shadows didn't get any darker. :( Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure your cube has that material assigned? On your screenshot, the Plane is selected and showing its Material.001, not the cube...

Comment: My last image is my updated screenshot. "Ambient" is the material I assigned to the cube and plane. It's supposed to show up like the one in preview window?

Comment: then no idea.. can you attach your blend file using this link? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/